# Remove every second row border bottom line

Tags: html, css

I have a table, which has borders. I want to remove every second row bottom line (or better yet, from a specific row). How can I achieve it in CSS?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: `tr:nth-child(2n) { border-bottom: none; }`

Comment: Search for `nth-child` maybe then you can make an example of your try and code

Comment: @belwood I'm doing it in WordPress table plugin, which allows custom CSS styling

Comment: @TylerH don't do it too easy ¬¬

Comment: @Danko I still voted to close the question which sends the message that it's not a good one. But if I can also help OP, no harm done.

Answer (score 2):

Use `:nth-child`

```
 :nth-child(even){border-bottom: none}
```